# Lightroom: Create virtual copy of image when dragging on collection

Tags: lightroom

When creating a collection in Lightroom I can have lightroom create a virtual copy for every image added upon creating the collection.

But when I add pictures later to the collection, I'll have to create the virtual copy by hand.

Is there an easy way to have Lightroom create a virtual copy when I drag an image on a collection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to make Lightroom 4 automatically create a virtual copy when dragging an image into a collection. However when virtual copies are created they are automatically selected (with any number of images selected), so the quickest way to get virtual copies into the collection would be to select the source images, use Ctrl + ' or Cmd + ' (as appropriate for your OS) to create the virtual copies and then drag them into the collection, which when I tried it was very nearly as fast as simply dragging images into the collection.